# Fix the command prompt when using boot2docker

Tags: macos, shell, command-prompt, boot2docker

I'm using boot2docker on OS X. If I open up a "normal" terminal, I get the following command prompt:

```
<machinename>:<currentfolder> <user>$
```

E.g., when logged in, in my home folder, on my notebook it is:

```
Schneehase:~ golo$
```

When starting a terminal using boot2docker, I just get

```
bash-3.2$
```

no matter where I am. How can I fix this (and how can I make this permanent)? I am using OS X Yosemite.

Comment: What does `echo "$PS1"` say at that `boot2docker` shell? What about in your normal shell?

Comment: In my boot2docker shell, it is `\s-\v\$`, in my normal shell it is `\h:\W \u\$`.

Comment: And there's your difference. Set the variable in your docker shell init script to the value from your OS X shell or anything else you want. `man bash` explains what you can do there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prompt is controlled by the `PS1` environment variable.

Your OS X shell and the boot2docker shell have different values for this variable.

Run `echo "$PS1"` in both shells and then set the boot2docker one to match the one you like.

See the bash man page "Prompting" section for more about what you can do with `$PS1`.